# LZ4_decompress_safe vs LZ4_decompress_safe_partial

Tags: compression, lz4

What is the difference between `LZ4_decompress_safe` and `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial`? I understand that `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial` does partial decompression, but it looks like `LZ4_decompress_safe` also can do partial decompression or I am wrong. Both function signatures have input and output buffers and both have sizes of those buffers as function arguments. And that's why I am asking about it. Say I have a buffer with compressed data and want to decompress only a portion of it. What would be the difference between using [LZ4_decompress_safe](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.h#L150) and [LZ4_decompress_safe_partial](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.h#L219). Would I get the same result?

Comment: LZ4 compresses data into blocks. I believe the difference is that LZ4_decompress_safe will always decompress an entire block while LZ4_decompress_safe_partial will let you terminate early. Have you checked to see if they produce the same result?

Answer (score 1):

> it looks like `LZ4_decompress_safe` also can do partial decompression

That's incorrect.
`LZ4_decompress_safe()` is expected to decompress full blocks, only.
It will return an error code if one tries to use it for partial decompression.

Generally speaking, `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial()` is more powerful, because it can do both full and partial blocks. That being said, its strength is its weakness : if your application wants to know if the block was fully decoded or not, `LZ4_decompress_safe_partial()` will not provide a useful signal for that: it will happily stop in the middle of the block if instructed to do so. It's also slightly more complex, internally, which may result in slightly slower decoding speed.